# angularJs. ng-messages-multiple not working

Tags: angularjs

hello I have a problem with this directive does not show me the multiple message, 
only one by one, I would like to show me the two messages in the same div
here example here an example of my problem
problem

Answer (score 0):

`<div ng-messages="myForm.myName.$error" style="color:maroon" ng-messages-multiple>
        <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
        <div ng-message="email">email wrong</div>
        <div ng-message="minlength">Your field is too short</div>
        <div ng-message="maxlength">Your field is too long</div>
    </div>`

[enter link description here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tteEnbUk1tJSm9xiv5nW?p=preview)